# Find the value of $a$,the value of $b$ and the value of $c$

Tags: area, rectangles

A rectangle has sides of length $x-3$ units and $ax^2+bx+c$ units,where $a,b,c \in \mathbb Z$.

The area of the rectangle is $2x^3-13x^2+25x-12$ square units.

Find the value of $a,$ the value of $b$ and the value of $c.$

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Da08a.png)
How would I answer this?

Comment: Where did this problem come from? I don't think it says what its author meant it to say.

Comment: It was a question my teacher gave me from studyclix.ie.

Comment: What I think the author meant to say was that $(x-3)(ax^2+bx+c) = 2x^3-13x^2+25x-12$ for every possible value of $x.$ But what the author actually _said_ was that there is a particular rectangle one of whose sides is $x-3,$ so $x$ is $3$ plus the length of that side, and $(x-3)(ax^2+bx+c) = 2x^3-13x^2+25x-12$ for _that particular value_ of $x.$ It's an awkward question. (I would answer it the way it was meant to be posed, but I would try to avoid this kind of ambiguity in my own writing.)

Comment: That would make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Area of rectangle is $l\cdot b$

So, $$(x-3)(ax^2+bx+c) = 2x^3-13x^2+25x-12$$

Multiply and compare like powers of $x$